# 2nd snippet of PHP code not working

Tags: php, html, code-snippets

I have a PHP file that has two sets of php code.  The first works fine, the second, not so much.  The file renders the first set of php code perfectly, then renders a form, then, instead of running the second set of php code, it prints it out, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Rate your favorite movie</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>

<html>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"> </div>   

            <div class="col-md-5" style="background:#2b1b17;color:white">

                <?php  //  FIRST SET OF PHP CODE

                    function get_movie_information($name) {
                        $url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=".urlencode($name); 
                        // send request 
                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);

                        return json_decode($curlData, true);
                    }

                    $arr = get_movie_information($_POST["name"]);

                    echo "<br>"; 
                    $poster = $arr['Poster'];
                    echo '<img src="' . $poster . '">';
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo $arr['Title'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $arr['Year'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $arr['Rated'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $arr['Genre'];
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo $arr['Plot'];
                    echo "<br>";

                ?>

                <form Id='Form' Method='post' Action='index.php'>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Movie">
                </form>

                <?   // SECOND SET OF PHP CODE
                    $hostname='127.0.0.1';
                    $username='root';
                    $password='password';

                    If(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        try {
                            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=baboon;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

                            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO movies (title, year, rated, plot) VALUES (:title, :year, :rated, :plot)");

                            // old code that didnt work
                            //  $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title); 
                            //  $stmt->bindParam(':year', $year);
                            //  $stmt->bindParam(':rated', $rated);
                            //  $stmt->bindParam(':plot', $plot);

                            $stmt->execute(array(
                                $title = $arr['Title'];
                                $year =  $arr['Year'];
                                $rated = $arr['Rated'];
                                $plot =  $arr['Plot'];
                            ));

                        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                        }

                        $db = null;
                    }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Somehow everything after $db->setAttribute is getting printed

Comment: So, is it everything after $db->setAttribute, or second set of php code? Did it print verbatim `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO movies (title, year, rated, plot) VALUES (:title, :year, :rated, :plot)");` onwards? Or did it only print out `// SECOND SET OF PHP CODE` onwards?

Comment: For your second set, don't use short tags. Please use `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: There is an <html> tag after <head> ?

Comment: It printed out everything after '$db->', which was 'setAttribute' on down

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues I noticed while reviewing your code:

1. Your `<head></head>` tags are outside the `<body></body>` tags.
2. Your second php tag is labeled only as `<?` not `<?php` like your first php tag.
3. The `if` you have in the second php code has a capital 'I'.

Comment: when I labeled the second tag <?php it wouldn't run at all, an empty page loads